# How does Grid operate on Dataset?

Tags: dataset

The documentation (10.0.2) indicates that Grid can be used to display a Dataset; the section in guide/ComputationWithStructuredDatasets labelled 'Dataset Presentation'.  However simply invoking Grid[aDataset] echos Grid wrapped around the Dataset.

e.g. `Grid[Dataset[{Association["a" -> 1, "b" -> 2], Association["a" -> 3, "b" -> 4]}]]`

Is there trick I'm missing here or is the documentation just misleading or out of date (in either direction; functionality not yet implemented)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that the documentation is listing `Grid`, `Column`, etc for *Dataset Presentation* in a generic sense.  By that I mean that those functions have no special behaviour defined for dataset objects, but they are useful to visualize the kinds of data that we are likely to find in datasets.

For example, we can use some of those presentation functions in conjunction with the dataset in the question like this:

```
dataset = Dataset[{Association["a" -> 1, "b" -> 2], Association["a" -> 3, "b" -> 4]}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
dataset[Grid, Values]
```

[image: grid screenshot]

```
dataset[Column, MenuView]
```

[image: column/menuview screenshot]

```
dataset[Row, TabView]
```

[image: row/tabview screenshot]

Comment: That (dataset[Grid, Values]) is 90% of what I was after.  It would be nice if the column headings could be persuaded to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing where in the help you saw it, its hard to interpret the full context but Grid can certainly be used to arrange datasets :

```
someDS = {<|"ID" -> 1, "Value" -> 100|>, <|"ID" -> 2, 
 "Value" -> 250|>} // Dataset;

Grid[{{someDS, someDS}, {someDS, someDS}}]
```

[image: Gridded DS]

Although this is the literal answer - I suspect you were looking for something a little more revealing?

Comment: Here's a online link... http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComputationWithStructuredDatasets.html. About 2/3 of the way down.  In your example Grid is showing Datasets in the grid, I want the Dataset (well a 2-D one) unpacked into the grid.

Comment: @Ymareth I think you're correct in assuming its either for forthcoming functionality or simply my answer or a mistake.  There dont seem to be any sections marked "new" in any of their help pages, and I had a good scan on Columns and couldn't find any references to Dataset.